# Why and how the displacement affects the texture's color?

Tags: displacement

I'm trying to understand the Math and MixRGB's options and stuck at the easiest one. Addition.

The setup:[image]

The left term: [image]

The top row right term's X location is -0,5.

The bottom row result: [image]

And my question is why they are getting darker at the top? If I increase the midlevel, or decrease the scale I get the expected result, but why and how the displacement affects the texture's color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at it, it doesn't seem to make sense. However, you have to be aware that on a flat plane the *Quadratic Sphere* gradient looks 2-dimensional, but it is in fact a 3-dimensional gradient which goes in all directions in 3D space.

The brightest part, the value 1, is at the center of a sphere - not a circle. From there it decreases to 0. It's not the displacement that affects the color, it's the texture itself.

The *Displacement* node tries to map 2-dimensional textures into height. So if you now take the *Quadratic Sphere* texture at a certain level - at XYZ = 0 for example - the textures values there get added and the gradient goes from 0 on the outside to 2 in the center.

This means, the displacement will use a height of 2 at the center - the peak you can see. However, the gradient which gives the color is still a *Quadratic Sphere*. So the brightest part with a value of 2 is at the center of the peak's bottom. From there it gets darker down to 0 and wherever the mesh meets this gradient in 3D space, this is the color it shows.

Imagine it like this, the left one is your result, the planes to the right like reference images when you're modeling something from blueprints for front, right and top view. As you can see by the dotted yellow lines, this is where your mesh lies in the 3-dimensional gradient. That's why not even the brightest parts on the outside have a value of 2, not even 1.

[image: quadratic sphere]

By the way, if you want the color to represent what the *Displacement* node uses as height, you have to turn the 3-dimensional gradient into a 2-dimensional gradient: simply set the Z scale in the *Mapping* node to 0.

[image: flattened texture]

Or in the "blueprint" view:

[image: flattened2]

Comment: really well explained! +1

Answer (score 5):

First of all, thanks for a really nicely presented question.

This is just a side-note to @Gordon Brinkmann's [equally nicely explained and illustrated answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/254088/35559).

Where *Object* Space is evaluated after displacement, *Generated* Space is evaluated before it.

So textures mapped in *Generated* space will follow the displaced surface around:

[image]

.. which can make complex combinations of procedural displacements much easier to handle, especially when you are displacing in more than one dimension, with *Vector Displacement* .

[image]

Comment: Nice addition. The only reason I'm not using _Generated_ very often is that many times I'm taking gradients like _Spherical_ or _Quadratic Sphere_ which I want to calculate from the center. With _Generated_ this means, I have to offset it in XYZ. If I then also don't have a square or circular plane, but rectangular or elliptical, I have to furthermore scale it differently on the axis to secure a circular shape. This often dampens some of the advantages of _Generated_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann True. There's a reason all those Nodevember contestants kick off with a nice, symmetrical cube/sphere.. :D